# Respostas "Consegui Resolver"

Tags: debate

As respostas "Consegui Resolver" cada vez me parecem mais comuns pelo SOpt. Exemplos como [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/430411/69296) e [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/328248/69296) são alguns dos exemplos que encontrei em menos de 30 segundos de procura.

Esse tipo de resposta (tão pouco fundamentada) é válido? Até por que me parece que elas são muito específicas ao caso de uso do próprio usuário que as *respondeu*. Literalmente um mero complemento à pergunta.

Algo precisa ser feito em relação a isso, ou é implicância da minha parte?

Comment: Em ambos os casos o problema era a pergunta aberta. Fechei as duas, e converti as "respostas-comentário" em comentários de fato, na pergunta. Se acha que um post não é resposta de fato, basta sinalizar como "não é resposta". Se for de fato uma solução (apresentada na resposta, não só um "aviso" de que resolveu), mas for realmente mal elaborada, sinalize como de baixa qualidade. E sempre tem a negativação, quando entender apropriado. Lembrando que tudo parte de resolver antes de mais nada os problemas das perguntas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em geral não são boas respostas e podem ser consideradas inválidas. É aquele coisa, a resposta responde bem à pergunta? Ou é só um *link*, ou um comentário, algo que não ajuda outras pessoas?

Respostas oficiais precisam realmente responder, não importa quem deu a resposta e qual o objetivo. Se a resposta for errada ainda é uma resposta, ruim, infeliz, de baixa qualidade, que não ajuda, não ensina, então um negativo vai bem, quem sabe alguma sinalização de baixa de qualidade.

Mas quando a informação é tão pequena, é tão inútil que nem pode ser considerado uma resposta real e completa para a pergunta, então ela é comentário e o melhor é sinalizar para transformar em comentário.

O Bacco tem razão nestes casos que o problema já partiu da pergunta.

Algumas pessoas não gostam, muitas vezes essas pessoas nem participam muito do site e só se importam com perguntas que lhe interessam, não debatem aqui, não olham esses exemplos e não conseguem enxergar bem porque perguntas precisam ser fechadas. Este é um exemplo do motivo. Uma pergunta ruim não pode produzir uma resposta boa, pelo menos na maioria dos casos. Se fosse possível um boa resposta talvez a pessoa tivesse dado uma. Por isso que fechar é importante.

E você está certo em indicar que as respostas são muito específicas, não atende bem os critérios do site que a pergunta deve produzir respostas que sejam gerais para a comunidade, ainda que em cima de um problema que a pessoa está tendo agora quando está codificando. Mas a culpa é da pergunta.

Se a pergunta for mais bem feita quem sabe outra pessoa possa responder e dar uma solução melhor que o AP achou. Ou mesmo ele poderia dar uma resposta melhor porque a pergunta é boa.

No fundo o problema é a pergunta, como quase sempre. Pode não ter sido terrível a SE aumentar a pontuação dada para boas perguntas, desde que sejam dadas ferramentas melhores e fique mais claro para todos que se não for boa a pergunta não merece crédito algum, até que seja editada para se tornar boa. (mas deixo claro que considero a valorização das perguntas um equívoco conceitual, respostas ajudam as pessoas, perguntas **boas** ajudam as boas respostas surgiram, é outro parâmetro, o maior ganho da pessoa que pergunta deveria ser uma boa respota e não pontos).